# implementing request-reply pattern in .net

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

Just wanted to know if i am going in the right direction or not.

I am implementing Request-Reply (Request-Response) pattern in which every operation sends a request object and gets response object back.

For Example:

```
Public FetchCustomerResponse Fetch(FetchCustomerRequest searchObject)
```

I am kind of in a confusion about implementing my Repository. I have a generic repositiry interface like this:

```
public interface IRepositoryReadOnly<TGetRequest, TGetResponse> : IDisposable
{
    TGetResponse FetchAll();
    TGetResponse Fetch(TGetRequest reqObject);
}

public interface IRepositoryReadWrite<TGetRequest, TGetResponse, TPutRequest, TPutResponse> : IRepositoryReadOnly<TGetRequest, TGetResponse>
{
    TPutResponse Insert(TPutRequest dto);
    TPutResponse Update(TPutRequest dto);
    void Delete(long id);
}
```

The Problem i am having is in `void Delete(long id);`.

I want my delete method to accept an object which contains other fields like `UserName, TimeStamp` etc.

Should i create a DeleteRequestObject with the properties and add it to the `IRepositoryReadWrite`?

This is how it will look if i do that.

```
public interface IRepositoryReadWrite<TGetRequest, TGetResponse, TPutRequest, TPutResponse, TDeleteRequest, TDeleteResponse> : IRepositoryReadOnly<TGetRequest, TGetResponse>
{
    TPutResponse Insert(TPutRequest dto);
    TPutResponse Update(TPutRequest dto);
    TDeleteResponse Delete(long TDeleteRequest);
}
```

Since the DeleteRequest and DeleteReponse objects will be same for all the operations (i think so), will this be a good implementation or am i completely off track here and doing all wrong?

Comment: `TDeleteResponse Delete(TDeleteRequest request);`, you meant to say in the last line of the last code sample, right?

Comment: A request-response pattern only really makes in a loosely coupled system, where the communication protocol is not strict. When objects communicate between each other, they can have a more explicit contract between each other, enforced by the compiler. A request-response pattern in this case can introduce unnecessary noise into the code. You might consider if it is really necessary.

Comment: In domain driven design repositories provide access to entities or aggregate roots. I think the request/response pattern does not really fit for repositories. The request/response pattern is usally used in the service layer of an application. Some kind of assembler class or helper method is translating between request/response objects and domain objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you may go this way, extra Request-Response objects will definitely not harm you.

If at some stage you, for example, find out that you are constantly deleting some entries by id, and to do that you regularly have to create a full request object with one property filled, you can always create an extension method - or even native class method, if you'd like to - that will accept `long id` and construct the request object for you.

If you leave it with just ids, then on some stage you'll possibly need the request object, but modification will be a whole lot more difficult.